# Regex to remove link but keep image inside

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have little problem with regex which removes links from html text.

I have this kind of links in my string variable.

```
<a href="https://slovan.azureedge.net/_obrazky/full/10/25322.jpg" class="gallery-item" data-gallery="gallery" data-size="0x0" itemprop="contentUrl" data-toggle="lightbox"><img class="obrazok_sprava img-responsive img-responsive" src="https://slovan.azureedge.net/_obrazky/top.2017/10/25322.jpg" alt="Foto" width="100%" data-id="25322" /></a>
```

and I need to remove a href part (full A tag from beginning to end). Image tag I don't want remove.

This regex which I found there doesn't work.

```
html.replace(/<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href="([^"]*)"/g, "")
```

Thank you for help

Comment: What's with the ``\"``? --- You only need to remove the `href` part? Not the `<a>` tag itself? Just the attribute?

Comment: This is what I am getting from JSON API. It must be there.

Comment: Do you need to keep the `class`, `data-gallery` etc and just removing the `href`? Or are you trying to remove the `<a>` tag and all its attributes ?

Comment: If that is part of a JSON response, then I suggest you parse the JSON first. And you never answered my other question.

Comment: @Andreas Omg sorry, Yes of course is JSON aleady parsed. Regular exp should be for classic link without slashes.

Comment: Then edit the question and correct it. And maybe answer my other question.

Comment: @dtlvd I need remove full a href tag from beginning < to end >. Leave just image inner.

Comment: from <a href="xxx" xxxxx><img></a> I need to keep just <img>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<a href=\"https://slovan.azureedge.net/_obrazky/full/10/25322.jpg\" class=\"gallery-item\" data-gallery=\"gallery\" data-size=\"0x0\" itemprop=\"contentUrl\" data-toggle=\"lightbox\"><img class=\"obrazok_sprava img-responsive img-responsive\" src=\"https://slovan.azureedge.net/_obrazky/top.2017/10/25322.jpg\" alt=\"Foto\" width=\"100%\" data-id=\"25322\" /></a>";
var link = div.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
var imageText = link.innerHTML;
```

But I'm sure you are doing something wrong. In most cases, you should not need to parse html by self.

Comment: Thanks but I need regular exp. I need remove it from string not from DOM.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I still don't know exactly what you want but this is what you asked in your comment. If it's not what you want could you show me the example string you want to get?

```js
function showPicture(){
var jsonString = '<a href="https://slovan.azureedge.net/_obrazky/full/10/25322.jpg" class="gallery-item" data-gallery="gallery" data-size="0x0" itemprop="contentUrl" data-toggle="lightbox"><img class="obrazok_sprava img-responsive img-responsive" src="https://slovan.azureedge.net/_obrazky/top.2017/10/25322.jpg" alt="Foto" width="50px" data-id="25322" /></a>';
var regex = /(<img.*\/>)/;
var image = regex.exec(jsonString)[1]
$('body').append(image); //inserts <img class="obrazok_sprava img-responsive img-responsive" src="https://slovan.azureedge.net/_obrazky/top.2017/10/25322.jpg" alt="Foto" width="50px" data-id="25322" /> into the body and you can't click it
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body onload='showPicture()'>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want remove a href tag. Image I want to keep.

Comment: Do you want to only remove href="https://slovan.azureedge.net/_obrazky/full/10/25322.jpg" ?

Comment: No, I just want remove link tag. I want to prevent user click. Just show image

Comment: look at my edit and answer me if I understood you right